# Bash script to fill in a template

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I have looked for this elsewhere but not able to find something that matches my requirements.

The template below is the one I need to use :

```
dn: uid=$1,ou=home,dc=chan,dc=com

objectClass: organizationalPerson

objectClass: person

objectClass: inetOrgPerson

objectClass: top

cn: $2

sn: $3

userid: $1

userPassword:
```

I need to script in such a way that populates the following fields  $1,$2,$3,$4 with the input that I give it and then outputs to a new file thus allowing to run it using the blank template.

Comment: See also this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914220/bash-templating-how-to-build-configuration-files-from-templates-with-bash

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for something quite simple like a file `my_script` that contains:

```
cat <<XXX
dn: uid=$1,ou=home,dc=chan,dc=com

objectClass: organizationalPerson

objectClass: person

objectClass: inetOrgPerson

objectClass: top

cn: $2

sn: $3

userid: $1

userPassword:
XXX
```

To use the above, simply run:

```
sh my_script fred 100 200
```

which will output to stdout (and can be redirected to a file).

Comment: This gives me "my_script: 1: my_script: Syntax error: redirection unexpected"

Comment: I believe you mean to use two redirect arrows on the first line

Comment: And it took 3 years for someone to find that.  Kudos!

Answer (score 3):

Does there actually need to be a template file?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "dn: uid=$1,ou=home,dc=chan,dc=com" > $4
echo "objectClass: organizationalPerson" >> $4
echo "objectClass: person" >> $4
echo "objectClass: inetOrgPerson" >> $4 
echo "objectClass: top" >> $4
echo "cn: $2" >> $4
echo "sn: $3" >> $4
echo "userid: $1" >> $4
echo "userPassword:" >> $4
```

You would run ./SCRIPTNAME Value1 Value2 Value3 OutputFileName

otherwise

You script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$1
var2=$2
var3=$3
file=$4

cat TemplateFile > $file

sed -i "s/1/$var1/g" $file
sed -i "s/2/$var2/g" $file
sed -i "s/3/$var3/g" $file
```

and your template file would be

```
dn: uid=1,ou=home,dc=chan,dc=com 
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
cn: 2
sn: 3
userid: 1
userPassword:
```

Comment: Ah I did this when yours was one string, hold on I'll fix it.

Comment: Don't use repeated redirections.  Rather than slapping ">> $4" on the end of each line, just do `exec > $4` at the start.

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar problem with

#### elegant and short solution in one line with `perl`

Use `perl` to replace variables with their values:

```
export world=World beautiful=wonderful
echo 'I love you, $world! You are $beautiful.' >my_template.txt
perl -pe 's|\$([A-Za-z_]+)|$ENV{$1}|g' my_template.txt
```

The output: `I love you, World! You are wonderful`.

`my_template.txt` can contain variables prefixed with `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `eval` command may also do the job for us as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30872526/248616)

```
source $config_file
template_str=`cat "$template_file"`
eval "echo \"$template_str\" "
```